# Run jQuery function on each element in a class

Tags: jquery, class, function, dynamic, each

I've got a function that resizes images based on some criteria and would like it to calculate all elements within the `.z` class individually and then return them.

Using `.each` runs all of the images through the function, but returns the same dimensions for all of them. Not sure where I'm screwing up...

Test site is here:

http://brantley.dhut.ch/

(also have to work out the deal with the fade in before the image has been fully resized, but that will be another question)

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.z').respond();
});

(function($){
    $.fn.respond = function() {

        /* initialize function on window load and resize */
        $(document).ready(function() {
            dimensions();
        });
        $(window).load(function() {     
            dimensions();
        });
        $(window).resize(function() {
            dimensions();
        });

        /* declare affected elements */
        var pic = this

        /* set image's height or width depending on the browser window's size */
        function dimensions() {
            return pic.each(function() {

            /* declare variables */
            var browserWidth = $(window).width();
            var imgRatio = pic.width() / pic.height()
            var availableHeight = ($(window).height() - $('header').height() - $('footer').height() - 80)
            var browserRatio = browserWidth / availableHeight

            /* image sizing logic */
            if (browserRatio >= imgRatio) {
                if (browserWidth > 640) {
                    /* if the browser is landscape and bigger than mobile, set the image's height to fill the available space */
                    pic.height(availableHeight).width('auto');
                    //$('body').css('background', 'blue');
                } else {
                    /* it's mobile */
                    pic.width(browserWidth - 40).height('auto');
                    //$('body').css('background', 'red');
                }
            } else {
                /* if the browser is portrait, set the image's width to fill the page */
                pic.width(browserWidth - 40).height('auto');
                //$('body').css('background', 'green');
            }

            /* horizontally center content */
            pic.css('margin-left', (browserWidth - pic.width())/2);

            });

        };

    };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `pic.each()` and inside the function that is supposed to be called on every element selected by the jquery object "pic", you're using "pic" aswell. Try using `this` there instead:

```
return pic.each(function() {
        /* declare variables */
        var browserWidth = $(window).width();
        var imgRatio = $(this).width() / $(this).height()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function dimensions() {
            return pic.each(function() {

            /* declare variables */
            var browserWidth = $(window).width();
            var imgRatio = $(this).width() / $(this).height()
            var availableHeight = ($(window).height() - $('header').height() - $('footer').height() - 80)
            var browserRatio = browserWidth / availableHeight

            /* image sizing logic */
            if (browserRatio >= imgRatio) {
                if (browserWidth > 640) {
                    /* if the browser is landscape and bigger than mobile, set the image's height to fill the available space */
                    $(this).height(availableHeight).width('auto');
                    //$('body').css('background', 'blue');
                } else {
                    /* it's mobile */
                    $(this).width(browserWidth - 40).height('auto');
                    //$('body').css('background', 'red');
                }
            } else {
                /* if the browser is portrait, set the image's width to fill the page */
                $(this).width(browserWidth - 40).height('auto');
                //$('body').css('background', 'green');
            }

            /* horizontally center content */
            $(this).css('margin-left', (browserWidth - $(this).width())/2);

            });

        };
```